# onmouseover transition effect without jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use onmouseover for hover effects of the main site logo on my dev site http://www.new.ianroyal.co.

onmouseover changes the site logo image instantaneously, I was wondering if I could apply a transition effect (fade in, or just generally slow down the transition speed) without using jQuery.

Here is my code:

```html
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" ONMOUSEOVER='ian.src="http://new.ianroyal.co/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/IN-Logo.png" ' ONMOUSEOUT='ian.src="http://new.ianroyal.co/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/IN-Logo1.png"'>
  <img src="http://new.ianroyal.co/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/images/IN-Logo1.png" NAME="ian" class="header-image" alt="Ian Nelson" />
</a>
```

I've searched and searched but it seems the only solultions are with jQuery which I don't have a good enough grasp of yet.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css3 transitions.

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: url(image1.png) no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

div:hover {
    background-image: url(image2.png)
}
```

Old browsers will simply not animate the transition.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/jg7G3/
​

Comment: Thanks for this response - I'm going to go with it when I have some time to implement due to the fact that this was a non-jQuery answer like I asked.

@Andyl - I'm going to master Javascript first through Codecademy before I tackle jQuery but I already understand the power of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pure CSS3.

```
.fade {
opacity: 1;
transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

.fade:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  }
```

Example taken from [here](http://bavotasan.com/2011/a-simple-fade-with-css3/). There are lots of other possibilities but that should be a good start.

However, it will only work with browsers which support CSS3 Transitions. Internet Explorer especially is [late to the game](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp), and there are still [lots of people out there using it](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp) (and older versions of other browsers which don't support CSS3).

If you want a truly cross-browser solution which maximises support for older versions then JQuery really is the way to go. However hard it seems, the time invested in learning to do a fade will really pay off. And it will almost certainly be easier to learn how to do a bit of JQuery than to do an equivalent pure JavaScript solution which would give the same cross-browser compatibility that JQuery gives you for free.

Comment: I don't like IE too, but many corporate clients use it. Interesting but not for production code.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, just use CSS Transitions and the `:hover` selector, and leave JS out of it entirely, [comme ça](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/08/circle-hover-effects-with-css-transitions/).

Answer (score 0):

Learn jQuery. I promise it will make you happy in the long (and short) run. That being said, once you know jQuery, dive back into vanilla js so that you really understand how it works.

For example, your problem in jquery would be as simple as:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').fadeOut();
    $('a').attr('src', '{new image path}');
    $('a').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: actually `$('a img').attr('src', '{new image path}');`

Comment: Anyway this will not work as you expect, because `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` are async methods. fadeIn should start when fadeOut is completed ... `fadeIn('slow', function(){ ...change src and start fadeOut... })` ... look at the working example posted bellow

Answer (score 0):

Working example, just provide image1.jpg and image2.jpg in same directory:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(function() {

$('img').mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('on'));
    $(this).fadeIn();
  });
});

$('img').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('off'));
    $(this).fadeIn();
  });
});


});

</script>

<img width="100" height="100" src="image1.jpg" data-on="image2.jpg" data-off="image1.jpg">
```